# Multidimensional Array in Javascript with Non Numeric Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is their any way to create mutidimensional arrays in Javascript with Non Numeric Idex?

like the structure

```
                optionList[0]['id'] = "equals"; 
                optionList[0]['name'] = "Equals";

                optionList[1]['id'] = "not_equals_str"; 
                optionList[1]['name'] = "Does Not Equal";

                optionList[2]['id'] = "contains"; 
                optionList[2]['name'] = "Contains";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least some kind of object that will do what you want even if it's not really a "multidimensional array".

You create a mododimensionnal array.

And you populate it with simple javascript objects, which you can consider as some kind of maps for many purposes.

```
var optionList = [];
optionList.push({});
optionList[0]['id'] = "equals"; 
...
```

You can create it in one go :

```
var optionList = [
    {id:"equals", name:"Equals"},
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you should use *objects* as arrays with non numeric indices. So your structure will look as follows:

```
var optionList = [
    {
        id : "equals",
        name : "Equals"
    },
    {
        id : "not_equals_str",
        name : "Does Not Equal"
    },
    {
        id : "contains",
        name : "Contains"
    }
];
```

Comment: This is not exactly a multidimensional array, but an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Those are arrays that contain objects. It would look like this:

```
var optionList = [
    {},
    {},
    {}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can always have nesting of Objects.

```
optionList = [{
      id: "equals",
      name: "Equals"
   },{
      id: "not_equals_str",
      name: "Does not Equal"
   },{
      id: "contains",
      name: "Contains"
   }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to define an empty array and then push those details as object into it.

```
 var optionList = [];
 optionList.push({id: 'equals', name: 'equals'});
 optionList.push({id: 'not_equals_str', name: 'Does Not Equal'});
```

Hope this helps.